# Merge every two consecutive lines

Tags: unix

How can I merge every two consecutive lines in a file?

```
Reservoir
Dogs
1992
reviewed
by
Michael
Hareven
```

I need the output like

```
Reservoir  Dogs
Dogs       1992
1992       reviewed
reviewed   by
by         Michael
Michael    Hareven
```

I tried `awk 'NR%2?ORS=FS:ORS=RS'`  but it gave me like AB CD.

Comment: Kindly specify what kind of file it is , also have you tried using copy paste with excel or another software or you want it dynamically from command prompt. This details will help you get more specific answers about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line, save its value, and then for each subsequent line, print the previous saved value and the current text, and then replace the saved text with the current line:

```sh
$ awk 'NR == 1 { prev = $0; next }
       { print prev, $0; prev = $0 }' input.txt
Reservoir Dogs
Dogs 1992
1992 reviewed
reviewed by
by Michael
Michael Hareven
```

Comment: thanks , if i want to make the words in tow columns , like this

Reservoir       Dogs
Dogs             1992
1992.             reviewed
reviewed.      by
by.                 Michael
Michael         Hareven

Comment: I have no idea what you mean; comments are not the place for formatted text. Needs to be in a question.

Comment: I want to split the words into 2 columns, each column separated by (3 spaces). I have modified the question،

Comment: Ah. You can use `printf` instead of `print`, with appropriate formats to get the column widths you want.

Comment: i tried many times , and it doesn't work with me , i am beginner , if u can help me with it