# How do you find the most two consecutive words in a text using awk?

Tags: awk

if ur text like

> **Reservoir  1992    reviewed by         Reservoir Har       even      RESERVOIR  DOGS**

first thing u have to do is to put the all the words in a one column ,

```
tr -s '[[:punct:][:space:]]' '\n'


Reservoir 
1992    
reviewed
by         
Reservoir 
Har       
even      
RESERVOIR  
DOGS
```

then u have to merge every two consecutive lines using

```
awk 'NR == 1 { prev = $0; next }
           { print prev, $0; prev = $0 }'
```

Output:

```
Reservoir  1992
1992    reviewed
reviewed   by
by    Michael
Reservoir  Har
Ha   even
even    RESERVOIR
RESERVOIR  DOGS
```

u can use  `printf` in place of `print`, to make the output like this? ( look to the answer down )

```
Reservoir  1992
1992       reviewed
reviewed   by
by         Michael
Reservoir  Har
Har        even
even       RESERVOIR
RESERVOIR  DOGS
```

then u `-sort` then `uniq -c` then `sort -nr`

Comment: It's as easy as you may expect. Please try: `printf "%-10s %s\n", prev, $0`. You can wrap the arguments with parentheses for clarity such as `printf("%-10s %s\n", prev, $0)`.

Comment: It doesn't work well, I edited the answer to see what the output looks like

Comment: What is the rule of the expected output? The order is not same as input and I don't understand why `Hareven` is broken into two separate words. It has nothing to do with `printf`.

Comment: I have a document that each line contains one word, I want to make every two consecutive words on one line, so that each word is in a separate column ..

Comment: I edited the answer to see what  i mean

Comment: As your expected output totally changes each time you edit, I cannot understand what you want. I'm afraid I cannot help. Bye.

Comment: If you run your awk program on the input you show there is absolutely no way that it produces the output you show. Please edit your question and fix all typos in it (`Har` v.s. `Ha`, no `Michael` in the input...). Do not type the inputs, the outputs and the awk program. Actually run your awk program on your real input file and copy-paste all this. Also add the expected width of the first column, including the spaces. No comments, no images, just edit your question and read it again 2 or 3 times to verify that it is now 100% clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge every two consecutive lines unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608973/merge-every-two-consecutive-lines-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

```
awk 'FNR==1{prev=$1; next}
{printf "%s\t%s\n", prev, $1; prev=$1}' file
```

Produces the *word order output* you state.

This:

```
awk 'FNR==1{prev=$1; next}
{printf "%s\t%s\n", prev, $1; prev=$1}' | column -t
Reservoir  1992
1992       reviewed
reviewed   by
by         Reservoir
Reservoir  Har
Har        even
even       RESERVOIR
RESERVOIR  DOGS
```

produces the output format. Note spacing to get even column width is variable. To produce that in awk, you usually need to go through the file twice in order to set the width of the column. The unix utility `column` will do that for you.

If you want awk to do it all, you might do something along these lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{length($1)>max ? max=length($1) : max=max; next}
FNR==1{prev=$1; next}
{printf "%-*s\t%s\n", max,prev,$1; prev=$1}' file file
Reservoir   1992
1992        reviewed
reviewed    by
by          Reservoir
Reservoir   Har
Har         even
even        RESERVOIR
RESERVOIR   DOGS
```